# MYSQL Start the cumulative sum() at 0

Tags: mysql, sum

my problem is that i want a cumulative total for a day. The SQL statement works so far, only that the sum should start at 0. At the moment it starts with the last summed value.

```
SELECT datetime,
   recb,
   ( SELECT sum( recb )
     FROM   fritzboxdaten1h
     WHERE  datetime <= m.datetime ) AS sumrecb
   FROM   fritzboxdaten1h AS m WHERE datetime Between '2020-11-06 00:00' And '2020-11-06 23:59'
   GROUP BY datetime
```

Output:

```
datetime             recb   sumrecb
2020-11-06 01:00:00  52.1   81396.8
2020-11-06 02:00:00  53.6   81450.4
2020-11-06 03:00:00  55.1   81505.5
2020-11-06 04:00:00  61.0   81566.5
```

It should output that though

```
datetime             recb   sumrecb
2020-11-06 01:00:00  52.1   52.1
2020-11-06 02:00:00  53.6   105.7
2020-11-06 03:00:00  55.1   110.8
2020-11-06 04:00:00  61.0   171.8
```

**What would the solution be?**

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried copying the date filter in the where clause into your sub-query?

Comment: A stick without a lollipop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming WHERE datetime Between '2020-11-06 00:00' And '2020-11-06 23:59' happens before the subquery is executed - that is not the case you need to include the condition in the subquery

```
SELECT 
   datetime, recb,
   (SELECT SUM (recb)
    FROM t
    WHERE datetime <= m.datetime 
      AND datetime BETWEEN '2020-11-06 00:00' AND '2020-11-06 23:59') AS sumrecb
FROM   
    t AS m 
WHERE 
    datetime BETWEEN '2020-11-06 00:00' AND '2020-11-06 23:59'
GROUP BY 
    datetime;
```

The group by in the main query is pointless and syntactically incorrect in some versions of SQL and can (should be) be removed. You should also include an order by in the subquery.

```
SELECT datetime, recb,
   ( SELECT sum( recb )
     FROM   t
     WHERE  datetime <= m.datetime and datetime Between '2020-11-06 00:00' And '2020-11-06 23:59' order by datetime ) AS sumrecb
FROM   t AS m WHERE datetime Between '2020-11-06 00:00' And '2020-11-06 23:59';
```

or if on v8 or above you can use window functions

```
select datetime,recb,
         sum(recb) over (partition by date(datetime) order by datetime) sumrecb
from t
where date(datetime) = '2020-11-06'
order by datetime
```